Run atmoz sftp on test container using ssh key without password
I am trying to run sftp using atmoz/sftp image in GenericContainer for an integration test.
I want to run it using ssh keys without password.
I am taking help of this solution here.
First I am creating ssh keys to test foo user:
ssh-keygen -f foo and saving it in src\test\resources\keys directory.
This is my test:
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.MountableFile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class SftpContainerTest {

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        try (
                GenericContainer<?> sftp = new GenericContainer<>("atmoz/sftp:alpine-3.7")
                        .withCopyFileToContainer(
                                MountableFile.forClasspathResource("testcontainers/", 0777),
                                "/home/foo/upload/testcontainers"
                        )
                        .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("keys/", 400),
                                "/home/foo/.ssh/keys/")
                        .withExposedPorts(22)
                        .withCommand("foo::1001")
        ) {
            sftp.start();
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session jschSession = jsch.getSession("foo", sftp.getHost(), sftp.getMappedPort(22));
            jschSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            jschSession.connect();
            ChannelSftp channel = (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            assertThat(channel.ls("/upload/testcontainers")).anyMatch(item -> item.toString().contains("file.txt"));
            assertThat(
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(channel.get("/upload/testcontainers/file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    )
                            .lines()
                            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))
            )
                    .contains("Testcontainers");
            channel.rm("/upload/testcontainers/file.txt");
            assertThat(channel.ls("/upload/testcontainers/"))
                    .noneMatch(item -> item.toString().contains("testcontainers/file.txt"));
        }
    }
}

But I am getting com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail in jschSession.connect();.
Container logs:
2024-12-07 13:49:27 [entrypoint] Parsing user data: "foo::1001"
2024-12-07 13:49:27 Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
2024-12-07 13:49:27 Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.
2024-12-07 13:49:27 Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub.
2024-12-07 13:49:27 The key fingerprint is:
2024-12-07 13:49:27 SHA256:KyH9k12zLVwFW3/U4Ah7pelIklcONc2ZnAIgYggEoTT root@9f0d8d3d6851
2024-12-07 13:49:27 The key's randomart image is:
2024-12-07 13:49:27 +--[ED25519 256]--+
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |o+E. .o . +o==+0=|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |.. ... . o B BO++|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |.       o = O.o==|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |         + = + +*|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |        S . o *.o|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |         . .   o |
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |          .      |
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |                 |
2024-12-07 13:49:27 |                 |
2024-12-07 13:49:27 +----[SHA256]-----+
2024-12-07 13:49:27 Generating public/private rsa key pair.
2024-12-07 13:49:30 Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.
2024-12-07 13:49:30 Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub.
2024-12-07 13:49:30 The key fingerprint is:
2024-12-07 13:49:30 SHA256:j+pEXDjExttPFAafCEURFnfvoUBevcFz/67uibICsKU root@9f0d8d3d6851
2024-12-07 13:49:30 The key's randomart image is:
2024-12-07 13:49:30 +---[RSA 4096]----+
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     oooO==.oo   |
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     A++ C.* .= .|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     .+oo.=   o=.|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     o.+. .. o...|
2024-12-07 13:49:27 Creating mailbox file: No such file or directory
2024-12-07 13:49:30 Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
2024-12-07 13:49:30 Server listening on :: port 22.
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |      + So  . . .|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     o . o.     .|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |      . .      . |
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     . . . .  . +|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 |     .o   ..o..+o|
2024-12-07 13:49:30 +----[SHA256]-----+
2024-12-07 13:49:30 [entrypoint] Executing sshd
2024-12-07 13:49:44 Received disconnect from 172.17.0.1 port 59336:3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail [preauth]
2024-12-07 13:49:44 Disconnected from authenticating user foo 172.17.0.1 port 59336 [preauth]

What am I doing wrong?
